# Google Chrome Packaged App - FTP mechanism

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, websocket, google-chrome-app

I'm looking to perform a simple FTP RETR of an image at a known server location from within a Google Chrome Packaged App. I'm exploring the following avenues:

1. XMLHttpRequest (which throws Exception 101: cross domain only allowed for HTTP)
2. TCP chrome.socket.write (sends packets OK, but no way to receive TCP data? **Edit:** *wrong*)
3. WebSockets (which throws Exception 18: WebSocket port 21 blocked)
4. `<webview>` (pulls the data alright in a sandboxed process, with no way to intercept it)

I've tried considering other possible approaches (my device runs a telnet server on port 23) but I don't think there are any shortcuts here.

Could my Chrome App possibly capture the webview's pixeldata in an HTML5 Canvas?

Have I overlooked any other communications mechanisms? All guidance appreciated.

**Edit:** apsillers/sowbug's comment per `chrome.socket.read` has reopened avenue #2. Woops! Using this on the port per the PASV response allowed me to perform a stream and retrieve the image data - thanks.

If it helps anyone else, here's the beginnings of a [socket object](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/13a55df447b97b8275cf) and [ftp client](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aed60cb84074dbd4d1bd) which run in an extension/app.

Usage: `new Ftp('192.168.1.1', 21).retrieve('/path/to/file.ext', eofHandler);`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by no way to receive TCP data on option #2? Doesn't chrome.socket.read do that?

Comment: `chrome.socket` (specifically [`chrome.socket.read`](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html#method-read)) is definitely what you want. If you have specific problems using that, post them in your question.

Comment: you're right @apsillers - blonde moment here looking at `recvFrom`

Comment: @sowbug As first-in, could you refer me to the same in an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[chrome.socket.read()](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/socket.html#method-read) should do nicely.